Processing Python 2D list with for loops
I wrote the following code:
Test=[[0.0]*4]*4
for r in range(4):
    for m in range(4):
        Test[r][m] = m+r
        print(r,m,Test[r][m])
print(Test)

Why finally all rows within the list contain the values from the last "r" iteration, i.e.:
[[3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6]]

instead of
[[0. 1. 2. 3.], [1. 2. 3. 4.], [2. 3. 4. 5.], [3. 4. 5. 6.]]

which is generated when numpy 2D array is used?

expected output?

Changing the first line to Test = [[0 for i in range(4)] for i in range(4)] seems to give the expected output. The error must be due to the first line

Test=[[0.0]*4]*4 This creates an outer list that contains four identical references to the inner list.  Changing one of those inner lists changes them all, because they are the same object.

Changing a value in any of the sublists,seems to cause the value at this index to change in every list. i.e. if i do Test=[[0.0]*4]*4; Test[0][0] =1, the first element of every sub list changes to 1

Thank You very much :)
I really appreciate your clues
